# How to detect if abstract reaches a second page, in order to add a header

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, abstract, thesis

I'm writing a thesis for which the very first page (or 2 if it's long enough) is the abstract.  I have two formatting requirements that I can't figure out, when the abstract continues onto the second page:

1. how do I prevent the page number from showing up on page 2?  I can suppress it on page 1 with `\thispagestyle{empty}`, but I don't know how to do that for page 2 since I don't know where page 2 starts
2. how do I add a header that only applies to page 2?  Again, I don't know where to put this header declaration since I don't know where page 2 starts

Here are the actual instructions:

> If the abstract extends onto a second page, that page should be headed as follows:
>
> ```
> Jane Mary Doe – [University], [year of graduation]
> ```
>
> The abstract is not paginated.

If the abstract fits on 1 page, then there shouldn't be a second abstract page.  Can anybody help me understand this problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Note that nobody can answer your question without an MWE. Without knowing the class, packages etc. you are using any suggestions will just be whistling in the wind and more likely to be useless (at best) than otherwise. In the abstract what you do is: create a pagestyle for the second page; use `\pagestyle{mystyle}\thispagestyle{empty}\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}\cleardoublepage\pagestyle{standardstyle}...`

Comment: Hi @cfr !  Thanks for your comment!  Actually my problem is more about "detecting and acting upon whether the abstract text reached the second page" rather than "I have broken code, please fix", so it doesn't seem like an MWE would apply.

Comment: All questions need an MWE. Reread my second comment. Your current question tells us nothing useful at all. Providing an MWE is a courtesy to potential helpers, yes, but in this case it is also essential to getting some potential helpers. How should I know your current class and packages or how you manage headers and footers? Talented though this site's denizens are, their ability to read minds is sadly limited. What I've posted gives you the general strategy. The rest is merely detail and cannot be considered until the problem is sprecified.

Comment: Hi @cfr -- thanks for your comment!  However, you seem to be mistaken about the requirement of an MWE according to the link in your first comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, @cfr, as a Latex beginner your 2nd comment means absolutely nothing to me!  I would prefer to understand the code rather than simply copy/paste it into my file.  As I mentioned earlier, the problem is not that I have code that I can't get to work -- but rather that I do not know how to approach the problem at all!  So suggestions for how to manage headers and footers in the context of solving this general problem are more than welcome.

Comment: @MattFenwick, your MWE could be some like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1-10] 
\end{abstract}
\end{document}` but probably your thesis is not a `article` class, and in the preamble you have header/footer definitions. We must know this to help you modifying your MWE.

Comment: Your abstract is a one-time deal. My suggestion is to manually set the page style if it's a single page, and the same if it spans more than one page.

Comment: *Markus Kohm* once wrote something on a mailing list: »Who knows, that an MWE isn't needed, also knows how to solve the problem. Who doesn't know how to solve the problem needs an MWE« (translated)

Comment: @Johannes_B That should be our site motto! Zen a la TeX?

Comment: @Johannes_B @ cfr http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuotingNotThinking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no example to work on here, this answer involves some guesswork, and is indebted to the suggestion from @cfr in the comments.  I've included some comments in the code to explain it a bit.  The crucial (and rather clever) idea given by @cfr is to turn on a special page style for the abstract, but suppress it on the first page only.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% define a new page style
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ps@abstract}{%
    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hss Jane Mary Doe -- University of Oxford, 1264\hss}%
    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}% left same as right
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}% blank footers
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{abstract} % turn on the new page style
\thispagestyle{empty} % but turn it off for the first page
\begin{abstract}
    Here goeth a pithy summary of the wonderful text herein.
    \lipsum % add some dummy text to push us over 1 page
    % the new heading will appear on p2 of the abstract
\end{abstract}
\clearpage  % or \cleardoublepage if you are in two sided mode
\pagenumbering{arabic} % reset page numbers to 1 (only if you want to)
\pagestyle{plain} % or whatever style you want for the rest of the doc
\section{Introduction}

Here goeth the rest of the booke.

\end{document}
```

### Explanations

Page styles in LaTeX are defined and switched on in two stages:  to define a style `abc`, you define a new command `\ps@abc` that re-defines the four header & footer commands shown above.  You then switch to that style using `\pagestyle{abc}`.  If you want a page style to apply the current page only, then you can use `\thispagestyle{abc}`; the previous page style will resume on the following pages.

The standard styles are `empty`, `plain` (the default in `article` class), `headings`, and `myheadings`.
The [page layout section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) on Wikibooks has some useful reference material.
There are several packages available that simplify and extend these basic LaTeX mechanisms. You might like to try [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for example.

Page styles are applied when TeX gets to the end of a page, so if you switch headings half-way through a page the new style applies to the current page not the next one.  So it's usually a good idea to make sure that you have started a new page, before you switch heading styles.  The `\clearpage` command does that for you (and also ensures that any pending floats, such as `figure` or `table` environments, are placed before the new page starts).

Comment: This is very enlightening, thank you.  Just to make sure I understand conceptually -- `\newcommand{\ps@abstract}{...` creates a new page style, and `\clearpage` ensures that whatever comes after the abstract is on the next page?

Comment: @MattFenwick It also ensures that `\pagestyle{plain}` does *not* apply to the final page of the abstract.