# Title in the second page

Tags: header-footer

I need to put a title like (name, 2021) on the top of the second page of my abstract. My abstract has two pages so I know how to put anything before it but the second page has the remaining of the abstract so I don't know how to interrupt it and put my title there. Any help? Thank

Comment: please see the answer below which is explained already here -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171958/how-to-detect-if-abstract-reaches-a-second-page-in-order-to-add-a-header?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% define a new page style
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ps@abstract}{%
    \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{\hss Jane Mary Doe -- University of Oxford, 1264\hss}%
    \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{\@oddhead}% left same as right
    \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{}% blank footers
    \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{abstract} % turn on the new page style
\thispagestyle{empty} % but turn it off for the first page
\begin{abstract}
    Here goeth a pithy summary of the wonderful text herein.
    \lipsum % add some dummy text to push us over 1 page
    % the new heading will appear on p2 of the abstract
\end{abstract}
\clearpage  % or \cleardoublepage if you are in two sided mode
\pagenumbering{arabic} % reset page numbers to 1 (only if you want to)
\pagestyle{plain} % or whatever style you want for the rest of the doc
\section{Introduction}

Here goeth the rest of the booke.

\end{document}
```